# I cannot execute a DataFrame.take(n) on PySpark in Jupyter Notebooks. Why?

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables, py4j

Note: not all DataFrame but specific ones (see code below)

I am able to start a Spark session from jupyter. I can even create a DataFrame using `sqlContext.createDataFrame`, but whenever I try to execute an operation on the DataFrame like `.take` or `.head`, it fails and I get an error like this:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o212.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 5, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\khnajm\Spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 377, in main
  File "C:\Users\khnajm\Spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 372, in process
  File "C:\Users\khnajm\Spark\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 393, in dump_stream
```

My `JAVA_HOME`, `SPARK_HOME`, `HADOOP_HOME` and `PATH` enviroment variables are all set correctly. I also downloaded winutils.exe and saved in `%SPARK_HOME%\bin`

I'm running jdk1.8.0_231 and spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7 with winutils for hadoop2.7. I've tried setting the `PYSPARK_PYTHON`, `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS`, but they didn't seem to change anything.

I can run `.take` on a simpler DataFrame, but when I run it on `wordsDataFrame` below, it fails, despite it being of type DataFrame.

```
#Tokenize the text in the text column
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="SMS", outputCol="words")
wordsDataFrame = tokenizer.transform(data_df)
#remove 20 most occuring documents, documents with non numeric characters, and documents with <= 3 characters
cv_tmp = CountVectorizer(inputCol="words", outputCol="tmp_vectors")
cv_tmp_model = cv_tmp.fit(wordsDataFrame)
```